# Using functions to change variable names from upper to lower

Tags: r, function, character, names

I'm working with a bunch of SAS datasets and I prefer the variable names to all be lowercase, using `read.sas7bdat`, but I do it so often I wanted to write a function. This method works fine,

```
df <- data.frame(ALLIGATOR=1:4, BLUEBIRD=rnorm(4))
names(file1) <- tolower(names(file1))
```

but when I try to put it into a function it doesn't assign.

```
lower <- function (df) {names(df) <- tolower(names(df))}
lower(file1)
```

I know that there is some larger concept that I'm missing, that is blocking me. It doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your code. You probably meant `names(df) <- tolower(names(df))`

Comment: Good catch, I updated it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arguments in R are passed by copy. You have to do:

```
lower <- function (df) {
  names(df) <- tolower(names(df))
  df
}
file1 <- lower(file1)
```

Comment: Or `setNames(df, tolower(names(df)))`.

Comment: or use `setnames` from `data.table` do it by reference

Answer (score 3):

Although I don't see why you would do this rather than simply : `names(df) <- tolower(names(df))`, I think you should do:

```
 lower <- function (x) {tolower(names(x))}
 names(df) <- lower(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that I don't recommend using anywhere <s>other than the `globalenvironment`</s> but it does provide you some convenient shorthand. Basically we take care of the assignment inside the function, overwriting the object passed to it. Short-hand for you, but please be careful about how you use it:

```
tl <- function(x){
  ass <- all.names(match.call()[-1])
  assign( ass , setNames( x , tolower(names(x))) , env = sys.frame(sys.parent()) )
}

#  This will 'overwrite' the names of df...    
tl(df)

#  Check what df now looks like...
df
  alligator   bluebird
1         1  0.2850386
2         2 -0.9570909
3         3 -1.3048907
4         4 -0.9077282
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I'm trying to get my mind around environments and this is really clear of why what I did wasn't working.

Comment: @DanKS you're welcome. As I said, this might prove convenient if you're just reading in some data.frames and want to change the names in the global environment, but I definitely wouldn't rely on this programmatically. un-intended side-effects and all.